# Bitpacking with more than 64 bits

Tags: javascript

I have a list of numbers that I need to use as an object key. At the moment, I'm simply doing `list.toString()` and using the resulting string as a key, but I would like to directly encode the numbers into a binary format to improve performance.

For example, my program currently would take in `[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]` and encode it to `"1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9"`.

The new implementation would do something like this:

```js
const list = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]

let key = 0;
for (let i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
    // bitpack each number as a byte
    key <<= 4
    key += list[i]
    console.log(key & 0xF)
}

console.log("")

// unpack to ensure the data was not lost
for (let i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
    console.log(key & 0xF)
    key >>= 4
}
// the "1" was lost
```

The performance I'm looking to improve is the O(n) `toString()` call, not necessarily the object lookup itself since that should be O(1). Instead of pushing numbers to the aforementioned list, I would simply encode them with a bitshift.

This implementation works, but only for 8 values <= 15 due to JS numbers' size.

Is there a way around this limitation or an alternate approach to encoding a list of numbers as a key?

Comment: not sure, but would [BigInt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/BigInt) work for you?

Comment: Never looked into them, but it appears to work pretty well. I'll have to do some benchmarking to see if it's a performance gain or not though

Comment: Wow, yeah, @JaromandaX it seems like BigInt works in constant time which is nice.

I did some benchmarking and for 10000000 ops, the BigInt method stays around 220 ms while the toString method is around 3000ms and grows with the list size.

Cheers!